# Alignment of second line bibliography using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, alignment

I have a problem regarding hanging indentation of second line in bibliography did not align with a first line. My MWE was adopted from Legrand orange book template. What I want is making the same alignment for bibliography.

I try using \setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} but didn't work. If I remove numbers from options, the alignment looks normal but I prefer to have author-year and number format as modern book bibliography style.

[image: my bib]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Paper size, change to letterpaper for US letter size
top=3cm, % Top margin
bottom=2.8cm, % Bottom margin
left=2.5cm, % Left margin
right=2cm, % Right margin
headheight=14pt, % Header height
footskip=1.0cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
headsep=10pt, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
%showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname 
the#1\endcsname\hspace{1em}}
%CHAPTER HEADINGS
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]. 
{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) 
{\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]. 
{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-8cm) node [line 
width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=black,fill=white,fill 
opacity=0.5,inner sep=20pt]{\strut\makebox[17cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-8.1cm) node{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) 
{\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]. 
{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-8cm) node [line 
width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill 
opacity=0.5,inner sep=20pt]{\strut\makebox[17cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-8.1cm) node 
{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{220\p@}}} %200 = space below the picture

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) 
{\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]. 
{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-8cm) node [line 
width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill 
opacity=0.5,inner sep=20pt]{\strut\makebox[17cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-8.1cm) node 
{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{220\p@}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress, comma]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\usechapterimagefalse
\include{chap1}
\end{document}


\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[2]
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0cm}
\linespread{1.0}\selectfont
\bibliography{TestBib}
```

Comment: The `apalike` bibliography style is designed for author/year citations not numbered citations but you're loading `natbib` with the `numbers` option. If you want numbered citations use a style that is designed for them, like `plainnat`.  But if you really need to do this, the linked question will allow you to do it.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll try following that link.

Comment: That solution works. Thanks a lot Alan Munn, Mensch, Cragfelt, Stefan, Pinnow, and Mico .